# How can i sort a list from specifik criteria

Tags: list, math, inequalities

I have this list and I want to sort the list. This is just a smaller example of what I want to do, but I get the same error. I dont understand why I can't make this work.
I have tried using google to solve the problem but without luck.

```
lst = [3, 4, 5, 6]

if lst < 4:
    lst.pop()
    print(lst)
```

How can i do this it shows

TypeError:'<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your goal is to remove all elements in the list that are lesser than 4. You can use this simple `list comprehension` in order to achieve what you want:

```
lst = [3, 4, 5, 6]
lst = [elem for elem in lst if elem >= 4]
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: what if i want to do it for >=4 and <=5 can i put both inside ?

Comment: Do u want both conditions (i.e >= 4 and <=5) to be satisfied?

Comment: Try this: `lst = [elem for elem in lst if elem >= 4 and elem <= 5]`

Comment: It works but is there a way i can put an id. on the elemets ? so that i get 4 has id 1 and 5 has id 2 from the original list :) ?

Comment: Do you want to create a new list with the ids?

Comment: the list i am working on has 11000 elements and when i used your code on it to reduce it, i want to have the ability to se what id it had in the original list. if that makes sence

Comment: What about this: `lst = [[index,elem] for index,elem in enumerate(lst) if elem >= 4 and elem <= 5]` Output: `[[1, 4], [2, 5]]` (the first num is the id, the second num is the number)

Comment: What if i had 2 list that i sorted like that and wanted and to make a new list that would only contain the same index as the 2 list `lst = [[1,2], [4,5] , [5,2]] lst2 = [[3,4], [4,2], [6,3]]` and then i want a list where the index (first nr) is the same `lst_total =[4, 5, 2]` or `lst_total =[4]`

Comment: Can u rephrase ur question?

Comment: if there are 2 list with the same index is there a way that i can make a new list with all the index that goes agien for the 2 list ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223663/discussion-between-sushil-and-kristoffer-karlsen).